# Django + MongoDB on Heroku

Tags: django, mongodb, heroku, django-nonrel, django-mongodb-engine

I'd like to use Django with MongoDB on Heroku. In the their document, [Getting Started with Django on Heroku/Cedar : Postgres Database Config](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#postgres_database_config), says that some code is appended to `settings.py` to use the `DATABASE_URL`.

Is there any way to avoid this ? Because the `DATABASES` needs to be `django_mongodb_engine` here, also with other settings, e.g. (example dragged from [compSocSci](http://compsocsci.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/getting-started-with-django-heroku-and.html))

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
    'NAME': 'heroku_app1234567',
    'USER': 'heroku_app1234567',
    'PASSWORD': 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'HOST': 'ds031117.mongolab.com',
    'PORT': '31117',
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I have figured out the way to do this after contact to Heroku support.
All you have to do is remove the shared PostgreDB addon and the injected code
would not modify the `DATABASES`.

```
$ heroku addons:remove shared-database:5mb
```

And note that you still need to include `psycopg2` in your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: does this mean that the deployed version will work on postgresql and on the development (localhost) will work on mongodb !?

Comment: Couldn't find that add on.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you simply don't specify `DATABASE_URL` (if that' possible at all).